# A notion of relabelling sets

Tags: proof-explanation

I read an [article](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0166864120301139?token=24AC6A449EF53D9A1A1CF29BC77C92DE4465B2A999950FA39E9C6A1C0F6571B10E73247FE142EEB8B4DCCA36E18C14F5&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20221115042858) and find a statement in the proof that I highlighted below.

[image]

I do not understand, why we can do relabelling?
And I do not know, how to do relabelling based on statement above?
Can I relabel, for example, $I_{1,0}=X_2$, $I_{1,1}=X_3$, $I_{1,2}=X_4$, and $I_{2,0}=X_5$? 
Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: The point is that you have an infinite sequence of sets $I_{1,0},I_{1,1}$, etc., indexed by pairs of integers. But what you really want is a sequence of sets $X_1,X_2,\dots$, indexed by natural numbers. This can be achieved simply by changing the names of the sets appropriately!

Comment: @KentaS How if I relabel $\{0\}$ and $I_{n,i}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$, $i=1,2,\dots,m-1$ as $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $X_1=\{0\}$ and $X_n=I_{n,i}$ for $n>1$, thus we have $[0,1]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$? Can I change the index $j$ in the picture above by index $n$?

Comment: Then $I_{1,1}$ and $I_{1,2}$ will have the same label, but they may be different sets!

Comment: @KentaS oh, I see. So, I cannot change the index $j$ by index $n$, right?